# Cron says it runs commands but doesn't

Tags: cron

I have a very weird problem. I have a crontab which looks like this (this is the output of `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * touch /home/<user>/Desktop/crontest.txt
```

A sample output of `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog` gives:

```
Jun 19 09:49:01 set-l-me-l16039 CRON[8399]: (u0128861) CMD (touch /home/<user>/Desktop/crontest.txt)
```

Yet no file is created in my Desktop! Running the command in the terminal produces the text file crontab.txt but the cron job doesn't. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: I use `crontab -e` to edit my crontab. Also I should mention that the same happens on my other machine running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Do you have permissions for ur user in that directory?

Comment: In the real world, <user> is replaced with a real username, right ?

Comment: @Melebius I checked that thread and checked the first 4 answers and they didn't help.

Comment: @arjithn I do, and also <user> is replaced with a real username

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the command you used to edit the crontab and the output of `ls -ld /home/<user>/Desktop`. You can also try to log the output by adding `> /home/<user>/crontest.log 2>&1` at the end of your command. If the file gets created, post its contents. See also [Debugging crontab jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883069/debugging-crontab-jobs).

Comment: as always: USE ABSOLUTE PATHS. /usr/bin/touch